# Rule of thumb for using wait()

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, browser-automation

A rule of thumb for using wait() would be before navigating to a different page. For Ex :

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.title.startswith("Submitted!!"))
```

What would be other such instances where using wait() would be a good coding practice?

I ask because i have experienced that when my test scripts  don't work i just stick in a wait() for elements/pages to load .
However i don't want to introduce a wait() after every webdriver action because that would increase the test time.

So in your experience , what are the best practices to using wait() ?

Comment: +1 This question applies to more than just Selenium/Webdriver.

Comment: Yes I thought so but could not find a tag for 'coding practices' or 'best practices'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to wait whenever there's a condition that must be satisfied before the test case can proceed. Waiting for a page to load is one such condition; another might be waiting for an AJAX interaction to finish, or for an error message to display.

Sticking a wait() after *every* action is not productive. Sticking a wait before every action that must occur before another action can safely be performed is.

Answer (score 2):

As the WebdriverWait only waits until your expected condition is satisfied, I dont think your test will get delayed if your AUT's page and its elements get loaded on time.

Comment: Right, but still it would not be good practice too use explicit waits after _every_ webdriver action (which includes some implicit wait already). It is not necessary for a lot of actions and would just clutter the code, making it hard to read.

Comment: The  following are the type of waits i said about, it waits until the expectation is met                      new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("btnG")));
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("btnG")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("webdriver - Google Search"));

Answer (score 0):

In selenium you can set a 'sticky wait' for the session:

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Mark Smith.